# Hazelcast Projection fetch single field

Tags: hazelcast

I have question regarding hazelcast Projection API.

Lets say I want to fetch just a single field from an entry in the map using Portable serialization.

In this example a name from an employee.

I'm guessing I will be getting better performance in relation to network traffic and deserialization by using a projection like this:

```
    public String getName(Long key) {
    return map.project(
            (Projection<Entry<Long, Employee>, String>) entry -> entry.getValue().getName(),
            (Predicate<Long, Event>) mapEntry -> mapEntry.getKey().equals(key))
            .stream()
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
```

Instead of something like:

```
public String getName(Long key) {
    return map.get(key).getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Projection is a type of predicate that comes handy if you want to return only a part of the entire value object in a result set of many value objects. For one single key based lookup, it is an overkill. A map.get is a lighter weight operation than running a predicate.

Network traffic = not sure how much savings you will have as that depends on your network bandwidth + size of the object + no. of concurrent objects traveling.

Deserialization = not much saving unless the actual object stored as value is monstrous and the field you are extracting is a tiny bit.

If you are conscious of network bandwidth and ser/des cost then keep in-memory-format to OBJECT and use EntryProcessor to update. If you do not have anything to update then use ExecutorService.